# Extract images link from html text string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to extract all images link to so I can utilize all images freely. how to do in asp.net c#

```
<div>
    <img src="/upload/Tom_Cruise-242x300.jpg" alt="Tom_Cruise-242x300.jpg" align="left" border="0" height="300" width="242">
    sample text sample text sample text sample text 
    <img src="http://www.sharicons.com/images/rss_icon.jpg" alt="Icon" align="left" border="0" height="100" width="100">
    sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text</div>
```

**I Got the Solutions**

```
 string ProcessedText = Regex.Replace(sb.ToString(), "^<img[^>]*>", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML and query it using XPath syntax (like `XmlDocument`).

Answer (score 1):

I would use the HTML Agility Pack.
Then you can do something like this:

```
HtmlNodeCollection allImages = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]");
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do this is to put the string into a string called `myString`, then run the following code:

```
List<string> imagePaths = new List<string>();
while( myString.IndexOf("img src=") >= 0 ){
  myString = myString.Substring( myString.IndexOf("img src=")+9);
  imagePaths.Add(myString.Substring(0,myString.IndexOf("\"")));
}
```

The List `imagePaths` will now contain all the image links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTMLAgilityPack or your second option is regular expressions :)